# How To Rollback AWS CodeStar Lambda Functions Deployed Via CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

I'm creating a Nodejs microservice for AWS Lambda. I scaffolded by project using AWS Codestar, and that set me up with a CI/CD pipeline that automatically deploys the lambda function. Nice.

*The issue is that every time it deploys the lambda function it must delete and recreate the function, thus deleting any versions or aliases I made.*

This means I really can't roll back to other releases. I basically have use git to actually revert the project, push to git, wait for the super-slow AWS Code Pipeline to flow through successfully, and then have it remake the function. To me that sounds like a pretty bad DR strategy, and I would think the *right* way to rollback should be simple and fast.

Unfortunately, it looks like the CloudFormation section of AWS doesn't offer any help here. When you drill into your stack on the first CloudFormation page it only shows you information about the latest formation that occurred. **Dear engineers of AWS CloudFormation: if there was a page for each stack that showed a history of CloudFormation for this stack and an option to rollback to it, that would be really awesome**. For now, though, there's not. There's just information about the latest formation that's been clouded. One initially promising option was "Rollback Triggers", but this is actually just something totally different that lets you send a SNS notification if your build doesn't pass.

When I try to change the CodePipeline stage for deploy from CREATE_CHANGE_SET to CREATE_UPDATE I then get this error when it tries to execute:

> Action execution failed UpdateStack cannot be used with templates
>   containing Transforms. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID:
>   bea5f687-470b-11e8-a616-c791ebf3e8e1)

My template.yml looks like this by the way:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
- AWS::CodeStar

Parameters:
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: AWS CodeStar projectID used to associate new resources to team members

Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_ENV: staging
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: post
```

The only options in the CodePipeline "Deploy" action are these:

[image]

It would be really great if someone could help me to see how in AWS you can make Lambda functions with CodePipeline in a way that they are easy and fast to rollback. Thanks!